# Menu superior fixo no topo da tela

Tags: novo-recurso

Seria interessante se ao descer para buscar perguntas ou ler uma delas e descer por todos os comentários e respostas que o menu descesse acompanhando a leitura, para facilitar a saída da página atual para outras perguntas ou outros objetivos...

Comment: Qual menu exatamente? A barra preta, o menu perguntas/tags etc ou o menu da seção atual?

Comment: o ideal seria ele mudar de forma pra se adaptar melhor, pra ter tanto a parte preta quanto a parte dos botões (perguntas, tags, usuários...) e a logo

Comment: Acho que se a parte dos botões fosse fixa perderíamos muito espaço útil. Mas se for só a barra preta talvez seja interessante.

Comment: Mas aí o design pode ser alterado quando rolar a barra, os botões poderiam se acoplar na barra preta... algo do tipo

Comment: Esse tipo de *feature request* normalmente é negado e a instrução é "instale um User Script e personalize o site ao seu gosto".

Comment: Estava pensando numa melhor praticidade no acesso aos recursos do site pelos usuários...